# How to I manipulate a value in a class in Python?

Tags: python, function, class

So i'am new into classes in python, and i was struggling a little bit here :(. So I wanted to make a class point which contained coordinates (x, y). First I made a function which set the values and afterwards a function to print the values in a tuple. But then i wanted to manipulate the y coordinate to reflect along the x-axis. But suddenly it started to give me an AttributeError

Input:

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

  def print(self):
      i = (self.x, self.y)
      print(tuple(i))

  def reflect_x(self):
      self.y*=-1

p1 = Point(1,4)
p1.print()

p2 = Point(-3,5)
p2.print()

p3 = Point(-3,-5)
p3.reflect_x().print()
```

Output:

```
(1, 4)
(-3, 5)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/I'd/love/to/keep/this/private/Oef.py", line 22, in <module>
    p3.reflect_x().print()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print'
```

As you can se as long as i don't implement my reflect_x function I don't get an error.

My wish-to output:

```
(1, -4)
(-3, -5)
(-3, 5)
```

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: All works as expected, since `reflect_x()` returns nothing.

Comment: I urge you to think about what is going on here, and why you expected it to work: `p3.reflect_x().print()`, what do you think `p3.reflect_x()` returns? Why do you think you can call `.print()` on the return value of `.reflect_x()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was already pointed out, reflect_x() returns default value (None), since you didn't put any return there. If you are used to the programming language that endorses chaining methods, you should add `return self` in functions you wanna use like that.

```py
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x, y):
      self.x = x
      self.y = y

  def print(self):
      i = (self.x, self.y)
      print(tuple(i))
      return self # change here

  def reflect_x(self):
      self.y*=-1
      return self # change here

p1 = Point(1,4)
p1.print()

p2 = Point(-3,5)
p2.print()

p3 = Point(-3,-5)
p3.reflect_x().print()
```

therefore allowing your methods to be chainable. [A nice video about it](https://youtu.be/BY34Fe-2xgk).

Answer (score 1):

Apply it directly to the object:

```
p3 = Point(-3,-5)
p3.reflect_x()
p3.print()
```

As opposed to the result of reflect_x(), which doesn't return anything.

Comment: Hi, thank you! I made the reflext_x function return x (x = self.y*-1). But for some reason the y coordinate doesn't get multiplied by -1. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your current code, though you can use -abs(self.y) instead of multiplying by -1 incase your operators aren't quite correct

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you are trying to print the state of your `p3` Object after calling `reflect_x`, right?

For that I would suggest to use `p3.print()` below your last line like you did before. You cannot call `print` that way, because it is trying to find it as a function of what `reflect_x` returns, which is `None`, and not you Class.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it's quite simple. When you call the `p3.reflect_x().print()`, it means you call the `print()` function from the `p3.reflect_x()` object. But the `p3.reflect_x()` means the object return from `reflect_x()` function of `p3` object. And here it is None because you dont return any thing from your code. 
 So you just add the return in `reflect_x()` function and it will work. It will look like this:

```
def reflect_x(self):
      self.y*=-1
      return self
```